# Create variables based on array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array and a loop fetching the keys (https://jsfiddle.net/ytm04L53/)

```
var i;
var feeds = ["test_user_201508_20150826080829.txt:12345","test_user_list20150826:666","test_list_Summary20150826.txt:321"];

for (i = 0; i < feeds.length; i++) {
    var feed = feeds[i];
    alert(feed.match(/\d+$/));
}
```

[image: array result]

The array will always contain different number of keys, What I would like to do is either use these keys as variables and assign the value after the `:` semicolon as its value or just create a new set of variables and assign the values found on these keys to them.

How can I achieve this? so that I can then perform some sort of comparison

if (test_user > 5000) {dosomething}

**update**
Thanks for the answers, how can I also create a set of variables and assign the array values to them? For instance something like the following.

```
valCount(feeds.split(","));

    function valCount(t) {
     if(t[0].match(/test_user_.*/))
      var testUser = t[0].match(/\d+$/);
     }
```

Obviously there is the possibility that sometimes there will only be 1 key in the array and some times 2 or 3, so `t[0]` won't always be `test_user_`

I need to somehow pass the array to a function and perform some sort of matching, if array key starts with `test_user_` then grab the value and assign it to a define variable.

Thanks guys for all your help!

Comment: Sorry didnt understand but what are you trying to do? Assign new values to the keys?

Comment: Use an object, not dynamically named variables. The latter is prone to all sorts of unexpected failures and security vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't (reasonably) create *variables* with dynamic names at runtime. (It is *technically* possible.)

Instead, you can create object properties:

```
var feeds = ["test_user_201508_20150826080829.txt:12345","test_user_list20150826:666","test_list_Summary20150826.txt:321"];

var obj = {};
feeds.forEach(function(entry) {
    var parts = entry.split(":"); // Splits the string on the :
    obj[parts[0]] = parts[1];     // Creates the property
});
```

Now, `obj["test_user_201508_20150826080829.txt"]` has the value `"12345"`.

**Live Example:**

```js
var feeds = ["test_user_201508_20150826080829.txt:12345","test_user_list20150826:666","test_list_Summary20150826.txt:321"];

var obj = {};
feeds.forEach(function(entry) {
    var parts = entry.split(":");
    obj[parts[0]] = parts[1];
});
snippet.log(obj["test_user_201508_20150826080829.txt"]);
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your code, in any case, if I wanted to assign the values to static variables, how can I achieve this? please see my updated question.

Comment: @J.D: *"...if I wanted to assign the values to static variables..."* You don't. :-) I know you think you do, but that road is just (to use an 80s word) gnarly. The code to do it is convoluted, error-prone, has poor performance, is difficult to maintain, and most importantly of all **is unnecessary**. Using an object (or an array) is the right way to handle this kind of dynamic situation.  The update to your question shows you assigning to a `testUser` variable, but as you flagged up, there would need to be a dynamic number of them. That's what objects and arrays *are for*.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this, using the split function:

```
var i;
var feeds = ["test_user_201508_20150826080829.txt:12345","test_user_list20150826:666","test_list_Summary20150826.txt:321"];

for (i = 0; i < feeds.length; i++) {
    var feed = feeds[i];
    console.log(feed.split(/[:]/));
}
```

This outputs:

```
["test_user_201508_20150826080829.txt", "12345"]
["test_user_list20150826", "666"]
["test_list_Summary20150826.txt", "321"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the split method

```
var feeds = ["test_user_201508_20150826080829.txt:12345","test_user_list20150826:666","test_list_Summary20150826.txt:321"];

feedMap = {}
for (i = 0; i < feeds.length; i++) {
    var temp = feeds[i].split(':');
    feedMap[temp[0]] = temp[1];
}
```

Yields:

```
{
    "test_user_201508_20150826080829.txt":"12345",
    "test_user_list20150826":"666",
    "test_list_Summary20150826.txt":"321"
}
```

And can be accessed like:

```
feedMap["test_user_201508_20150826080829.txt"]
```

Here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/peteTalksWeb/pen/PPYobE)

Answer (score 1):

it is not very good idea but if you really need to create variables on-the-run here's the code:

```
for (i = 0; i < feeds.length; i++) 
{
    var feed = feeds[i];
    window[feed.substring(0, feed.indexOf(":"))] = feed.match(/\d+$/);
}

alert(test_user_201508_20150826080829)
```

Of course you cannot have any variable-name-string containing banned signs (like '.')

Regards,
Michał